# How t reintegarte branch of branch in svn

Tags: svn, merge, svn-reintegrate

I am using SVN. I have a branch created from another branch which in turn created from trunk. Now what is the correct procedure to rentegrate my branch to trunk?

```
-------------------------------------------- trunk
   \
    \________________________ Branch1
              \
               \____________ MyBranch
```

Answer (score 1):

`Mybranch` and `Branch1` both use the same method of reintegration: standard. Starting point of branch is unimportant

Comment: And the changes made in Branch1 after its creationg and before MyBranch creation?

Comment: @DiegoF.Durán - obviously **yes**, MyBranch at starting point have included all changes from Branch1 at this point (branching = copy of data)

Comment: A merge apply changes, not the existing code. If you merge MyBranch to Branch1 and there's any change in MyBranch dependent in a change exinsting in Branch1 prior to the creation of MyBranch you will have problems, maybe not conflict problems but logical ones.

Answer (score 0):

Merge back MyBranch to Branch1 and then Branch1 back to trunk, or reintegrate MyBranch to Branch1 and then Branch1 to trunk. I'm not a fan of --reintegrate, I prefer manual just merge the right revisions.

```
----(1)-------------------------------------- trunk    \
     \(2)_____(3)______________ Branch1
               \
                \(4)__________(5) MyBranch
```

Or, if you want go the hard way: merge from Branch1 to trunk the revisions from Branch1 creation to the Branch1's revision from where you created MyBranch, and then merge MyBranch to trunk.

If you know that there's no changes between (4) and (5) that depends in changes between (2) and (3) you can just merge MyBranch directly to trunk.

Comment: Why do you want to pollute Branch1 by changes, separated into special branch?!

Comment: Changes made between (4) and (5) may be logical dependent on changes made between (2) or (3). I explained above. Your solution is right if there's no functional dependencies between changesets :)

Comment: When I merge to trunk MyBranch, *all* changes **from common parent of two heads** will be applied - thus include all changes from (1) branchpoint. Do you want to see samples?

Comment: Please, I want to see a sample because Subversion doesn't work with snapshots but with changesets and if you do a svn merge -r4:5 MyBranch over a working copy of trunk you are doing just that, merging that revision range.